# next-sass: Flash of unstyled content only when building for production

Tags: webpack, next.js

## ✅ Solved, see my reply below!

I'm using Next.js with next-sass. I've been struggling with a flash of unstyled content "FOUC" issue my entire day, testing various solutions I found online, but none seemed to work for me. The issue is especially visible when using CSS transitions, as the components will be visible without any styles and then transition to their CSS style.

This is only visible when building for production using `next build` and then `next start`. In development mode, using `next`, there is no FOUC issue.

Minimal example:

```
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withSass();
```

```
// scss/style.scss
body {
    background-color: red;
    transition: 2s all ease;
}
```

```
// pages/index.js
import React from "react";
import "../scss/style.scss";

const Home = () => (
  <div>Test</div>
);

export default Home;
```

GitHub repo: https://github.com/jesperlindstrom/next-sass-fouc/

Video of problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12yukgmgsuPKRs0TD2yYZK9F7fBC7oSkF/view?usp=sharing

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce your probem put a github repo please

Comment: @evgenifotia thanks for checking it out. I added a GitHub repo and a video clip just now.

Answer (score 0):

So... the issue turns out to be a browser bug, not related to Next or Webpack at all. Managed to replicate with ordinary CSS and HTML, where transitions are fired on load. The solution sounds very stupid but solves it: import an empty .js file in your . I'm guesing it makes both the resources "blocking" and therefore waits for first render...

If anyone has the same issue in Next.js, I added this to my _document.js:

```
<Head>
...
<script src="/static/chrome-fix.js" />
</Head>
```

...and put `chrome-fix.js` as an empty file in my /static.

More info: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332189